# Return first ID matching a sequence of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create and Populate POC tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #POCSTBL (SCode varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #POCSTBL (SCode)
SElECT 'LC13'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'LC22'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'LC31'

CREATE TABLE #POCLUTBL  (ID int Identity (1,1), LC1 varchar(10), LC2 varchar(10), LC3 varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #POCLUTBL (LC1, LC2, LC3)
SELECT 'LC11',NULL,'LC13'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'LC21','LC13',NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT '-','LC31','LC33'

SELECT * FROM #POCSTBL
SELECT * FROM #POCLUTBL
```

My Initial Try:

```
SELECT S.SCode, LU.ID FROM #POCSTBL S LEFT JOIN #POCLUTBL LU
ON S.SCode = LU.LC1 OR S.SCode = LU.LC2 OR S.SCode = LU.LC3
```

Drop #Tbls:

```
DROP TABLE #POCSTBL
DROP TABLE #POCLUTBL
```

Desired Output:

```
SCode   ID
LC13    2
LC22    NULL
LC33    3
```

I want to lookup SCode column from #POCSTBL against #POCLUTBL's 
LC2 first, if found, take that ID as output, 
if ID not found then LC1, if found, take that ID as output, 
if ID not found then LC3, if found, take that ID as output, 
if ID not found then ID = NULL

Thank you

Comment: #POCSTBL = POC Source Table
#POCLUTBLE = POC Lookup Table
SCode = SourceCode
LC(1/2/3) = Lookup Column (1/2/3)...oh that was me btw who came up with these names. :P

Comment: TIL: I need to be more simple and less weird. Thx Aaron ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    S.SCode, 
    COALESCE(L1.ID, L2.ID, L3.ID) As ID 
FROM      #POCSTBL  S 
LEFT JOIN #POCLUTBL L1 ON S.SCode = L1.LC1 
LEFT JOIN #POCLUTBL L2 ON S.SCode = L2.LC2 
LEFT JOIN #POCLUTBL L3 ON S.SCode = L3.LC3
```

Assuming that there are not potential duplicate SCodes in LC1, LC2 or LC3.  If there may be, then you will need a more complicated version of this.

Comment: this is like dark magic...COALESCE = getting the first non-null value from the (L1.ID, L2.ID, L3.ID) options, what is the logic behind multiple LEFT join and their join conditions? Thx for this awesome sln (I just don't quite get it at this point in my life).

Comment: Each LEFT JOIN extends the column set of the base table.  L1 adds columns for all of the `#POCLUTBL` rows that match LC1 to the SCode.  L2 adds columns for rows that match on LC2 and L3 adds columns for LC3 matches.  Now with all of the potential matching values as addl columns in the same row, COALESCE can scan through the *columns* and find the first one that is not NULL.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you are creating 3 instances of same tbl #POCLUTBL and getting multiple finds. Doing COALESCE to get the first non-null value. What I don't is how does your query skip SCode : LC13, ID:1?

Comment: nvm, I think it's making sense now that I added SELECT...L1.ID L1,L2.ID L2, L3.ID L3,.. just need to pull a few more hairs.

Comment: Ok, the more I look at this, I think the order in which the output came is a coincidence..let me explain. If I wanted to lookup L3 first then L2 and then L1 to get ID, this wouldn't work. In that case, would I need to make changes to COALESCE from COALESCE(L1.ID, L2.ID, L3.ID) As ID to COALESCE( L3.ID, L2.ID, L1.ID) As ID?

Comment: @user1569220 Yes, in this query COALESCE is determining the order of defaulting.